# Unable to Cancel Orders in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I would like to add the option for customers on my site to cancel their orders, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I've created the view and the URL, but something is evidently wrong with them. Here's how it looks on the site:

[image: Cancel Order]

delete_order View:

```
def delete_order(request, pk):
    """ Cancel an order from the profile page """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        order.delete()
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, "delete_order.html", {'item': order})
```

Order Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    town_or_city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    street_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    street_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self.id, self.date, self.full_name)
```

Django Url:

```
url(r'^delete_order/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', delete_order, name="delete_order")
```

Html Url:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_order' order.id %}">Cancel</a>
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image: Error Message]

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you use `a href` it always do `GET` request so there is no chance to delete Order so remove `if request.method == "POST":` if condition check

Comment: So, should it now look like this?

`def delete_order(request, pk):
    """ Cancel an order from the profile page """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    order.delete()
    return redirect('customer')

    return render(request, "delete_order.html", {'item': order})`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot to add end slash in the main urls.py file?
When you connect app urls to main urls.py file you need to check that url link looks like:

```
path('checkout/', include('checkout.urls')),
```

Comment: You were right that I missed the slash, but it didn't fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
def order_remove(request,pk): 
order = Order.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
order.delete()
return redirect('#your path#',pk)
```

user first to get that particular order

```
path('delete/<int:pk>', views.delete_order, name="delete_order")
```

Comment: That hasn't worked for me unfortunetly. Is this correct what I've done?

`def delete_order(request, pk):
    """ Cancel an order from the profile page """
    order = Order.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    order.delete()
    return redirect('customer')

    return render(request, "delete_order.html", {'item': order})`